# Using a while loop instead of for to count words and locate instances in string

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, while-loop

this time I have more code to add to the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079318/counting-total-words-in-string-counting-spaces). Our TA wants us to write a function and then print the total number of words in the string, were each word is a group of characters seperated by a space, print the number of `<B>` tags, and print the number of hyperlinks.

The sample input is:

```
#statHTML("<B> Article One </B> <a href=http://news.google.com>News</a>")
```

BUT he wants us to ONLY use WHILE loops. I have finished it but only with FOR loops. Please assist as I cannot get it and even my friends are stuck

This is the code that I have so far.

```
str1T = len(str1.split())
print (str1T_strat_two)
str_t=str1.count('<B>')
print (str_t)
total = len(str1.split('<B>')) - 1
print (total)
print (str1.count('href'))
```

Comment: it took the hyperlink I had in there and converted it to a link. sample input is #statHTML('<B> Article One </B> <a href=http://news.google.com>News</a>')#

Comment: Check the formatting guide.  You can make stuff into `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide to get you going.

```
string = "Article One News"
words = string.split()

i = 0
while i < len(words):
    word = words[i]
    # Do whatever you want with this word
    i += 1
```

You can put whatever code you need in place of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert any for loop to a while loop by turning this

```
for x in y:
    #stuff
```

into this

```
try:
    x = next(y)
    while 1:
        #stuff
        x = next(y)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```